# How to validate an e-mail if this is not same as other model's e-mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise

I have 2 variables "email" and "umail". umail belongs to user-model and email belongs to other model. I want to validate umail, which content shouldn't be same as email. e.g. If umail: "abcd@xxx.com" and email: "abcd@xxx.com", then umail shouldn't be saved and an error message should be shown.

I tried to write devise validation "exclusion" like

```
validates :subdomain, exclusion: { in: User.current.email,
   message: "%{value} is not allowed to use }
end
```

But no success, so I tried:

```
class Tecdb < ApplicationRecord
validates :umail, presence: true, if: :umail_not_allowed
def umail_not_allowed
  errors.add( umail: "is not allowed to use" ) if :umail == User.current.email
end
```

But also no success (means, even umail and email are same, umail was saved without showing any error message).

Can someone let me know how is the best way to write for this kind of validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
validate :check_email_and_umail

def check_email_and_umail
  errors.add(:umail, "can't be the same as email") if umail ==  User.current.email
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean,  I need to modify the code `validates :umail, presence: true, :umail_not_allowed` ? This shows a syntax error

Comment: make sure you have written 'validate ' and not 'validates'.  Also can you show the syntax error